# Running total quick calculation in Tableau with two different groupings

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following chart, which uses Quick Table calculation to count the percentage of the values across the group Category for each month.

[image]

What I want is to count the percentage of the **monthly running total** of the values across the group Category for each month. I can create the quick calculation for monthly running total, separately, but I can't seem to combine it with this below because one requires quick calculation across the table and another across the group. Can anyone advise if this is doable?

The workbook attached [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5548442/StackOverflow%20attachments/FY13%20vs%20FY14.twbx), with the problem above in the second tab.

**Edit**: Let me give example what I meant here:
April: A = 1000, B=500, C= 200, D=300 -> total is 2000
percentage in April in chart is A = 1000/2000 = 50%, B = 25%, C = 10%, D = 15%, total = 100%

May: A=2000, B=2000, C=1800, D=200 ->
cumulative April+May A=3000, B=2500, C=2000, D=500 -> total is 8000
percentage in May in chart is A=3000/8000 = 37.5%, B = 31.25%, C = 25%, D = 6.25%, total = 100%

Comment: That's a rather simple request, though I couldn't find a solution. Problem is you need a TOTAL(RUNNING_SUM()), which Tableau does not allow (a table calculation inside total()). Sorry I cannot help, try Tableau community and support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer elsewhere and thought I should update here. The solution was to use a **secondary table calculation**. Basically, after putting `SUM(Value)` pill in Row:

- right click on it to select `Add Table Calculation`
- set as primary calculation the Running Total Sum of Table (Across)
- check the box to `Perform a secondary calculation on the result`
- set as secondary calculation the Percent of Total of Table (Down)

See below screenshot of the setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for ways to calculate the sum of the running total across the category? it is not clear when you say to count the percentage? However if you are looking for sum of percentage running total across your category... you can edit your calculation and set the calculation type as running total, the summarize value ( you can choose, sum , average, min,...max) and the running along option choose category.

Comment: I've edited the question to give an example. I want the percentage in a category of the monthly running total. As Inox highlighted in comment, which I think is along the line of what you suggested, TOTAL(RUNNING_SUM()) (or average or other summarize value) doesn't seem to work on RUNNING_SUM()